# How to get row weights from a form before saving?

Tags: forms

I have form with an image upload field which saves multiple images. User can reorder and crop images in that form. **Reorder using default drag option**.

My requirement is to create a PDF of images in current order when user clicks on submit button.
I am taking the image uri from field values by loading node. So the order will be the saved order. I am creating the PDF inside **hook_insert**.

**How do I get the row weights before saving the node, so PDF can be created according to current order of images?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to get the row weights for the images.

The "weight" or list order of the images is stored in the `delta` value.

e.g:

```
$node->field_images[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'];
$node->field_images[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['fid'];
$node->field_images[LANGUAGE_NONE][2]['fid'];
```

The `delta` value is 0, 1 & 2 representing the first, second and third images respectively.

Also, if you're using one of the node API hooks, e.g `hook_node_insert`, you won't need to load the node, it should already be passed as a parameter there.

Comment: Itz worked. what i have done before is i passed $node, but again **load the node** and then took **fid**. Now its works perfectly...